# Run ffmpeg with ICMv audio codec

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg, codec, transcoding

Is it possible to transcode an `.wav` file that uses ICMv audio codec to a `.wav` or `.mp3` file that uses a traditional Codec?

- I have multiple files that uses ICMv audio codec and I would like to convert them to traditional audio files programmatically. My first solution so far was actually using Ffmpeg to transcode the audio file, but I had no success so far.

This is what I've tried so far:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input_file.wav output_file.wav

> ffmpeg output:
  Duration: 00:09:40.00, bitrate: 16 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: none ([34][34][0][0] / 0x2222), 8000 Hz, stereo, 16 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (? (?) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Decoder (codec none) not found for input stream #0:0
```

I also created a Python script to run the following command with all available codecs on Ffmpeg:

```
def transcode_file(input_file_url:str,output_file_url:str,codec:str):
    stream = os.popen(f'ffmpeg -i {input_file_url} -c:a {codec} {output_file_url}')
    output = stream.read()
    return output
```

And none of the available codecs on Ffmpeg could transcode the file correctly.

When I tried to open the file on Audacity, it says:

> "Audacity did not recognize this type of file, Try installing ffmpeg. For uncompressed files, also try File > Import > Raw Data"

- When I tried to open the file as raw data on Audacity, it sound like a random noise, no recognizable audio.

I also configured Audacity to load ffmpeg correctly after that, but it didn't work either.

I also tried to open the file on `mpg123` and it did not work either, but when I tried to open another audio file that uses a traditional Codec, it worked fine.

Comment: `ffmpeg` should be able to do it with the right options. What did you try? For just audio format conversion, I've used `mpg123`. You might try `avidemux` Also, `audacity` comes to mind. There are really a lot of tools--these are just a few.

Comment: @CraigEstey I've just updated the question with more experiments that I've made

Comment: A web search produces scant results. The codec _might_ come from a company called "PCS, Inc" It appears to be mostly/only Windows Media Player. No info on format or where to download any S/W. If you have anything that can play it, I'd use that S/W to divert to a raw file. Then, you can reencode. I don't know if WMP does this easily. But, you _can_ change the output audio device.

Comment: Found "virtual audio device" See: https://www.howtogeek.com/364369/how-to-record-your-pcs-audio-with-vb-cable/ and https://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it

Comment: Yeah, that's the only solution that I have so far. The company that I am working with, they gave me the Windows Installer for the Codec. So once I executed the windows installer, I could listen the audio on Windows Media Player. So I am using Audacity to record the audio played on Windows Media Player and export the recording as a traditional mp3 audio file. But @CraigEstey thank you for the support.